# Accessing Wso2 Api Manager from custom DNS

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, apim

I have a wso2 API manager 3.0.0 setup on my linux. By default, the publisher, dev tools and management console url points to localhost. In order to access it via browser, I had to replace **localhost** with my server IP and it worked.

Now I have created a DNS and want to access it via DNS. It doesnt work.

Could you please let me know the exact steps to achieve this? What all files should I be changing?

Please note, id rather change in the application configuration files than change the server's host file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to point the IP address of the server to DNS as an initial step. Then the request will route to your server.

As a second step, you have to configure the DNS hostname in the deployment.toml file, then the server knows where to route the request. Please refer to the documentation[1]

As a third step, you have to create a certificate with a new DNS hostname (CN) and change the primary key with the certificate. please refer to the documentation[2]

Can you provide what is the exception which you are getting with the new DNS route?

Thanks

[1]https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/deployment-best-practices/changing-the-hostname/
[2]https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/security/configuring-keystores/keystore-basics/creating-new-keystores/

Comment: Thanks. I tried the steps but when I visit the DNS , it just loops on its own without any error in the logs. 

I get this on the top left side of the page : "You will be redirected to /publisher/services/auth/login"